# how to display an activity by clicking on a button in another activity in android?

Tags: adk

i am a beginner in android app development.

i am trying to display an activity(named `MainPage1Activity`) by linking it with another activity(named `activity_main`) when a button is pressed in the `MainActivity`. 
i have used `intent` to link the two but when i run the app in emulator and click the button nothing is displayed.
do i have to use a function to use another function to display the other activity????
the code i used in main activity is:

```
public void viewalarm(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage1Activity.class);

}
```

Comment: you can vote this answer by clicking on arrow key and choose this your best answer and vote it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Add your Android Manifest configuration file

```
<activity android:name="NewActivity"></activity>
```